# PHP Mysql Display and join rows

Tags: php, mysql

a little dilemma for me here. my comments for broken over many lines as show by the line number. Unfortunately I have no control over this so I am left with trying to output this they way I want.

My data is as follow

```
Firstname | Surname | Linenum |CommentID | Comment
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bill      | Jean    | 0       |8876      | A Simple comment here
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob       |Jones    | 0       |7345      | This is a very long comment
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob       |Jones    | 1       |7345      | And is over many rows. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob       |Jones    | 2       |7345      | Thank you for reading.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tim       |Burton   | 0       |3719      | The quick brown fox jumps
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tim       |Burton   | 1       |3719      ! over the lazy dog
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So what I want to end up with is echo.....

```
Firstname: Tim
Surname : Burton
Comment : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I am really stuck on the sql for this and don't know where to start.

I can call and display for MySQL which I would call normally ! but when It calls joining from several rows I am at a loss.

Thank you for looking !

Comment: Can you post an example of your MySQL table? What are the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need query like this:

```
 SELECT firstname, surname, 
     GROUP_CONCAT( comment) as comment from table 
    where commentid=3719
   group by firstname, surname
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad ! really appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your query begs for [group_concat](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php). You will need to write a selection which will have

```
order by CommentID, Linenum
```

which will be a subselect. The outer select will use `group_concat` for `Comment` and

```
group by CommentID
```